# rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: "cargo" "--version" failed: program not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo, wsl-2, rust-analyzer

I have Rust installed using WSL2 Ubuntu I have alredy ran basic commands like hello world in rust so cargo is working. I wanted to download the rust-analyzer in VSCODE but I keep getting that error message from the title: **rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: "cargo" "--version" failed: program not found**

I tried ensuring all paths are correct, all vesions of extension and vscode and rust are up to date. several uninstall re-installs and rustup updates. Toolchain is using stable version. I have reviewed a lot of the other post about this accross all platforms but it seems I can not find the fix. It would be very helpful to get some guidance. Thank you!st

Comment: If you open a terminal in VS Code and type `cargo`, does it work ?

Comment: are you using the "Remote - WSL" extension?

Comment: Yes Cargo returns all functinos and works correctly. And I installed WSL locally on my PC.

Comment: If you're using a remote extension, try typing `cargo` on the remote.

Comment: Hi @ChayimFriedman I am not using a remote extension. Cargo does run.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to open folder as if in WSL.

- To do that you need to install this VS code extension called [Remote development](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)
- Than go to the green symbol in the bottom right corner and then select `open WSL folder` and open folder with your rust project or just open `new WSL window`

[image: remote development icon]

- The last step is to go to extensions and then search for `rust-analyzer` and hit install

More info regarding the development on WSL can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `rustc` and `cargo` provide by system package manager (e.g. `apt`).

Install them from [offical rustup script](https://rustup.rs/) instead.

[note]

I just encounter the same problem when using flatpak version of [Lapce](https://lapce.dev/).

`rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: "cargo" "--version" failed: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

Comment: solution for flatpak here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/2873#issuecomment-575815147 `flatpak --user override com.visualstudio.code --env=PATH=/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/$USER/.cargo/bin` or `dev.lapce.lapce` instead of `com.visualstudio.code` in case of Lapce

Answer (score 0):

another good option is open your wsl, move to the project folder and type `$ code .` or `$ code YOUR_PROJECT`, then install rust-analyzer extension